# Write webm data to file in lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have some webm data that I'm sending to a lambda via a multipart/form-data POST. I need to write that data to a /tmp file within the lambda so that I can add it to some existing videos via ffmpeg.

I'm trying to verify that everything is working correctly by writing the data to S3. I found that it works when I wrote it to S3 "directly" (see code below), but not when I write it to a tmp file first, and then upload that file to S3. When I write it to S3 "directly" and then go download the file from S3, it plays fine. However when I upload my lambda tmp file to S3 and then download it, that file doesn't work. The code is below:

```
    c_type, c_data = parse_header(event['content-type'])
    assert c_type == 'multipart/form-data'
    decoded_string = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
    c_data['boundary'] = bytes(c_data['boundary'], "utf-8")
    form_data = parse_multipart(BytesIO(decoded_string), c_data)
    
    with open("/tmp/audio.webm", "a") as audio_file:
        print(form_data['audio'][0], file=audio_file)
    
    # This file is not a valid .webm when I download it from S3
    boto3.resource('s3').Object('mybucket', 'test_print.webm').put(Body=open('/tmp/audio.webm', 'rb'))
    # This file is a valid .webm when I download it from S3
    boto3.resource('s3').Object('mybucket', 'test_data.webm').put(Body=form_data['audio'][0])
```

Here's an image of the two files (left side is invalid/uploaded from the file, right side is valid/uploaded to S3 "directly") when I download them from S3:

[image]

I suspect that there's just some encoding or write settings I need to set here to get it to actually write the binary to the tmp file, rather than a byte string, which is what the left side looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - needed to use "wb" (for write bytes) as my argument to open(). I also used BytesIO in the end:

```
with open("/tmp/audio.webm", "wb") as audio_file:
    write_byte = BytesIO(form_data['audio'][0])
    audio_file.write(write_byte.getbuffer())
```